# Setting up a LAN without configuration at all

Tags: networking, distributions

Is there a Linux operating system that is designed to set up local area networks easily, that is, without any configuration at all?

The main thing I'm trying to find out is if there is a dedicated operating system for setting up local area networks easily with 0 configuration, simply that all the computers with the same network will be connected by a network cable or Wi-Fi and that's it, from that moment, it will be possible to access each of these computers in a direct way, as if we entered a directory (as long as the other relevant computer on the network is powered).

All of the aforementioned computers are not laptops and aren't taken outside, they stay in the same building (unless the content of the building is moved to another building).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145615/discussion-on-question-by-somo-setting-up-a-lan-without-configuration-at-all); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. In fact, it's totally the default what basically any modern OS does, including Linux systems. You connect to a network, your PC does IPv6 autonegotiation, and the router announces its available IPv6 prefixes, out of which your computer automatically picks an address

> without a router

Without a machine that acts as a router, you obviously can't have internet access. That's what the word "router" means: it *routes* the packets between two networks (the internet and your LAN).

> it will be possible to access each of these computers in a direct way, as if we entered a director

That has nothing to do with setting up a LAN, that's file sharing, and nobody enables automatic file sharing on their OS, because that would mean when you take your laptop anywhere, join the WLAN there to get internet, all the others would see your files, which is not even worth discussing, but dangerous and potentially in violation of laws requiring the owner of data to secure it sufficiently.

So, while that is *possible* nobody programs their system to do that and for very good reason.

There's easy settings/wizards that allow you to set up file sharing, just as on windows, and Mac OS, for the different Linux desktops.

Comment: Do modern (created after 2020) network cards or mother boards also make a "physical router" (for lack of a better term) redundant?

Comment: You will have to find a better description, because "physical router" makes no sense. I don't understand you. And none of this has much to do with hardware, and there's nothing that fundamentally changed about network cards since maybe 2003…

Comment: Yes, my mistake, it's surfing outside the scope of my question. I have edited to re-ask only about software...

Comment: @somo no, you haven't, you just brought some unlogical hardware device into your question.

Comment: I don't understand you, I have just edited to remove the entire router/hardware topic out of my question...

Comment: It seems, what I am ought to use is not a LAN, but rather file sharing. I have never done that with a cable between two local computers (I only connected a pocket computer or another device to a local computer).

Comment: ok, so yeah, more or less back to the original question. So, ignore the section about "without a router" in my answer. It answers your question.

Comment: You even spelled out LAN meaning "local area network", which literally means "a network of devices that are co-localized"! I think the terminology confusion is the dominant problem here.

Comment: I would say, it's my ignorance about what is the difference between a "local area network" and "a network of devices that are co-localized"...

Comment: there is none. A LAN is a network that is local. that's it. That's what it means. it says nothing about what you *do* over that network.

Comment: there's even stuff like [mDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) that would make names work without a nameserver, and [link-local addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) and their autoconfiguration exists for IPv4 too. (Though usually when one sees 169.254, they think of misconfiguration, so, yeah.)